# Отладка JavaScript'а

Tags: javascript, html

Я провожу дебаггинг одной онлайн-игры от компании Mindorchard. В одном моменте там должен вылезать IFrame. Они начисто забыли о кнопочке "закрыть", и открыв IFrame, несчастные юзеры от него не могут избавится, он так и витает, как ужас на крыльях ночи, поверх игры и загораживает весь обзор. Я очистил главную страницу игры от всех прочих скриптов и CSS-стилей, оставил только голый механизм работы IFrame + библиотеки JQuery и JQuery.simplemodal. Вот как это выглядит:

```
<html>
<head id="ctl00_Head1"><title></title>
<sсriрt type='text/jаvаsсript' src='js/jquery.js'></sсriрt>
<sсriрt type='text/jаvаsсript' src='js/jquery.simplemodal.js'></sсriрt>
</head>
<body>
    <sсriрt type="text/jаvаsсript"> 
            function showTerms(urlToShow)
            {
                document.getElementById('iframe_termsAndConditions').src = urlToShow;
                $.modal(document.getElementById('basic-modal-content'),
                    {
                        opacity: 10
                    }
                ); // DOM                
            }
    </sсriрt>
    <!-- user input dialog -->
    <div id="basic-modal-content">
    <iframe id="iframe_termsAndConditions" frameborder="0" width="490" height="390" scrolling="yes"
        style="OVERFLOW-X: hidden">
    </iframe>
    </div>

    <a class="modalOpenImg" title="Open" href="jаvаsсript:showTerms('academyterms_us.html'); void(0);">OPEN</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Я в JavaScript'е совершенно не шарю, просто не успел выучиться =(. Гугл тоже не помог-все, что он выдавал, с этим кодом не работало. И еще, тут есть такой нюанс: из-за особенностей используемых CSS, в главной странице при открытии IFrame начисто зависает все, кроме SWF-объекта (самой игры). Так что единственный способ - сделать кнопочку "закрыть" в самом IFram-е.

Заранее благодарен за ответы.

-Mints97

Answer (score 1):

Закрыть фрейм повесив конопку внутри фрейма не получиться, так как эта кнопка будет реагировать на содержимое загруженной страницы внутрь фрейма, а не странице на которой расположен сам фрейм. Поэтому кнопка должна быть на той же странице что и сам фрейм.

Немного не ясно это: из-за особенностей используемых CSS, в главной странице при открытии IFrame начисто зависает все - я понимаю, что создается какой-то див, который гасит всю область, оставляя только окно с флешем. Если это так, то необходимо создать дополнительный элемент, на который можно повесить событие для закрытия фрейма. Нужно только посмотреть эти css и добавить сам элемент в разметку. А потом все просто, по клику на закрывающую кнопку, брать фрейм и ставить ему display:none либо вообще удалять его со страницы remove();

Answer (score 1):

```
var f = window.parent.document.getElementsByTagName('iframe');
for(var i = 0; i < f.length; ++i)
    if(f[i].src == location.href)
    {
        f[i].parentNode.removeChild(f[i]);
        break;
    }
```

Код не тестировал, но логика видна. В данном случае выбираются все iframe родительского окна и убивается тот, из которого запускался скрипт. Убивается именно iframe, а не модальное окно, будьте внимательны.

Answer (score 0):

Человека с файербагом попап-ами не испугать!
Используй браузер [Mozilla FireFox](http://www.mozilla.com/ru/firefox/) c [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/)
Firefox дополнение для этого браузера позволяющие менять страницу как угодно. [Инструкция по применению.](http://getfirebug.com/screencasts)